# How can I get file_id with Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm creating a Telegram Bot and I need to get `file_id`.for example, photos.

For example:

```
"AgACAgIAAx0CW7VwqQAD3GE80mUSC6AbGV2lcHFzI5J3me7zAAJwtTEbkWJISbKzPMDueHfrAQADAgADeAADIAQ"
```

Is there such a possibility and how can I do it?

If you need more information, ask. Thank you!

Comment: you can get `file_id` in `events` or `get_messages` method

Comment: Right, I can download the file, but is it possible to get file_id, in the format as I described in the question? It's just that I personally would be more comfortable getting the file this way than downloading it.

Comment: You want to use the `file_id` to access the file whenever you want ? If yes. I think it is better to forward the file somewhere and use the file from there. Because the `file_id` will expire.

Comment: No, I need file_id for a short time.

Comment: I found how to get such a file_id from the document, but when you try to get it from the photo gives an error: `'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'location'`. I tried to call it this way: ```event.file.id```

Comment: The method ```await client.pack_bot_file_id(event.photo)``` the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Telethon documentation shows what attributes [Document](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/document.html) and [Photo](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/photo.html) have.

So you can use the following code:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def downloader(event):
        file = event.document or event.photo
        file_id = file.id
```